# Thickbox hacking - removing fields

Tags: admin, uploads, thickbox, attachment-fields-to-edit

### Default (big and ugly) Thickbox

I don't like how this Thickbox's page looks at all, I almost never use all these settings fields so decided to get rid off them, at least on pages where I'm uploading images as theme options.
[image]

### A (very) simple Thickbox

Using [attachment_fields_to_edit](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_and_Attachment_.28Upload.29_Filters) & [media_upload_tabs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_iframe) filters I made it look much simpler:
[image]

If you're wondering how to do that (these filters/hooks are poorly explained), here's the code:

```
function thickbox_fields($form_fields, $post){
    unset(
       $form_fields['post_title'], //disables "Title" field and so forth...
       $form_fields['url'] );
       $form_fields['image_alt'], 
       $form_fields['post_excerpt'], 
       $form_fields['post_content'], 
       $form_fields['align'], 
       $form_fields['image-size'], 
    );

    return $form_fields;
}

function thickbox_upload_init(){
    add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', 'thickbox_fields', 10, 2);
}

add_action('admin_init', 'thickbox_upload_init');
```

### The trouble

Unfortunately after deleting image-size and url fields I'm not sure how to overwrite its values with desired content (in this case the url and image-size set to "full", always).

I'm uploading things based on [this simple yet powerful tutorial](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2010/01/08/using-the-wordpress-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/) using this code on admin page:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
 formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
 tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
 return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src'); //imgurl is always empty after deleting url field
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

And as comment states `imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src')` is just empty, in addtion when I disable just image-size and leave url alone - its size is always set to "medium", any ideas how to fix that?

I was trying to pass URL and image-size like this:

```
 function thickbox_fields($form_fields, $post){
        unset(
           $form_fields['post_title'], //disables "Title" field and so forth...
           $form_fields['url'] );
           $form_fields['image_alt'], 
           $form_fields['post_excerpt'], 
           $form_fields['post_content'], 
           $form_fields['align'], 
           $form_fields['image-size'], 
        );

        $form_fields['url'] = 'not sure how to get the url here, but this doesnt work anyways';
        $form_fields['image-size'] = 'full'; //yup, this also doesn't work at all

        return $form_fields;
    }
```

I know these fields are arrays, but `$form_fields['image-size'] = array('size' => 'full')`, doesn't work either.

Any hints?

**TL;DR** - how to hide url and image-size fields from Thickbox and then send value of url field's to front-end? Also, how to force Thickbox to upload files as "full", because with image-size unset it returns links to medium-sized uploads all the time.

I guess image_size_input_fields filter could be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tricky but once you understand how WordPress sets the sizes and the fields then the rest is easy:

```
function thickbox_fields($form_fields, $post){
    unset(
        $form_fields['post_title'], //disables "Title" field and so forth...
        $form_fields['url'],
        $form_fields['image_alt'], 
        $form_fields['post_excerpt'], 
        $form_fields['post_content'], 
        $form_fields['align'], 
        $form_fields['image-size']
    );

    //create the size input for full only and set display to none
    $size = 'full';
    $css_id = "image-size-{$size}-{$post->ID}";
    $html = "<div style='display: none;' class='image-size-item'><input type='radio' name='attachments[$post->ID][image-size]' id='{$css_id}' value='{$size}'checked='checked' /></div>";
    //set as image-size field
    $form_fields['image-size'] = array(
        'label' => '', //leave with no label
        'input' => 'html', //input type is html
        'html' => $html //the actual html
    ); 

    return $form_fields;
}
```

First you remove all unwanted fields, then you mimic the way WordPress creates the sizes field but only with full as the selected option and you hide that using `display:none`

and then you add it to the fields array in the way WordPress Accepts and as you can see its not just a simple string but an array of parameters (label,input,html)

Now for the real question: who is the girl in the image???

Comment: To be honest I was trying to mimic this field at first, but didn't know what do to with "html" element as var_dump was returning rendered html elements instead of raw data. And unfortunately, I don't know who the girl is, here's the original pic of her - http://i.imgur.com/gRasY.jpg :) Thanks a lot, and by the way where's Thickbox code stored within WordPress? I'm browsing media.php/media-upload.php but couldn't find anything like the code provided by you. I'd love to do the same trick with url and maybe hide "Save all changes" button.